# Maps is offline check Internet connection

Tags: google-maps

I seem to have an issue with Google maps, ever since the update that moves the timeline from the cloud to the device, all but one of my devices displays that when trying to access my timeline. This next part is not my main issue but might give some insight, once I accepted the update all the info on the cloud became inaccessible, but I know it's still there currently.

I've so far been told to clear data and reinstall maps etc. Currently I have done a fresh install on one of the devices, a Samsung S5 tablet, still the same issue. It only happens when trying to view the timeline and I'm connected with maps working in every other way.

Hopefully someone here might have some thoughts, if not, a good place to search for some answers would be appreciated